# Cursor Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: android, database, exception, indexing, cursor

In attempting to execute a query on my database, I get this exception.  However, the documentation states that the method `SQLiteDatabase.query(...)` returns, "A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry," which I interpret to mean that the Cursor is at the start of the rows returned.  If I add the `Cursor.moveToFirst()` before accessing data in the Cursor, I get no exception.  What is going on?  Do I need to always call "moveToFirst" before trying to get data?  The documentation says this method, "moves the cursor to the first row."

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLENAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
Log.d("TAG",""+c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
```

Comment: Please post the code around the area where this happens.

Comment: If it's "positioned before the first entry" - means you should call moveToFirst().

Comment: are you usign Cursor.hasNext() and Cursor.next() functions ? please provide some sample code where you got this error

Comment: I'm guessing the Cursor works similar to String indexes.  How it's inbetween letters instead of at a letter.

Answer (score 13):

After query you need to call `next()` or `moveToFirst()`. Cursors are lazy loaded, after calling these methods cursor is loaded into memory. You can decide when to do it.

Answer (score 2):

to iterate trough all rows:

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLENAME, null, null, null, null, null, null); 
while(c.moveToNext()) {
      int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_ID")); 
}
```

or you can use other cursor functions, for example moveToPosition() to access row specified by id

more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html