# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException for table and records existing

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am querying the database with the following query:

```
    final Cursor subject_cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB.Table.SUBJECT + " WHERE uniqueSUB = '" + cs_cursor.getString(1) + "'", null);
```

when i log the cursor count it gives me 1 as the count, but when i try to access the data using **subject_cursor.getString(0)** it gives me an error saying:

```
    05-30 03:37:10.921: W/System.err(5408): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

I have checked the database for the records manually and all the required data is present.
(Also if i just do a following query:

```
    "SELECT * FROM " + DB.Table.SUBJECT"
```

for the same table and give the get the count for the cursor it gives me the existing number of records which is correct).

Please Do Help...

Comment: Then there is a possibility that your query is not getting executed properly. What is the value of `cs_cursor.getString(1)` just beforethe query executes?

Comment: @Shobhit Puri it is 2

Comment: @ShobhitPuri i have checked and confirm it!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely read through the whole post [Cursor Index Out of Bounds Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743833/cursor-index-out-of-bounds-exception). It deals with exactly same problem and you can get the answer to your problem there. Taking from the post and adding to what @Alexey pointed out, `Cursors` are [lazy loaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_load) and you need to call [moveToFirst()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) or [moveToPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#%20moveToPosition%28%29) etc methods to load them into memory. `moveToFirst` moves the cursor to the first row, so that you can access it. Similarly, `moveToPosition()` moves the cursor to an absolute position. Without using these functions it will throw the error that you were getting. Hope this helps.

Comment: if cursors are lazy loaded then how come i get the columnname if i do:

        subject_cursor.getColumnName(0);

Comment: [getColumnName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnName%28int%29) returns the column name at the given zero-based column index. It does not depend on your rows that you get as query result. So it will work.

Comment: so after i query with the where clause and then use moveToFirst or moveToPosition then to get to the desired record, i'll have to query the table with the where clause again.... isn't it???

Comment: No. After querying, if you just want to get the value of particular column value of the first resultant row, then first move the cursor to the first row by `cursor.moveToFirst()` and then get the value in column with that index. i.e cursor.getString(columnIndexValue). This will give the value in the `columnIndexValue` column index for first row. It depends on what you want.

Comment: what i want i have described in the where clause... so its obvious i want record particular to that condition... so if i use subject_cursor.moveToFirst() then i don't get the record i need!!

Comment: ok i just got what i want.. Thanks for telling me about that cursor lazy loading thing... Thanks a lot.... i had been stuck there for last 24 hours!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped you. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(subject_cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    subject_cursor.getString(0);
```

Comment: ok.... u just needed me to explain the cursor lazy loading thing... ShobhitPuri helped me with that... thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
 final Cursor subject_cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB.Table.SUBJECT + " WHERE uniqueSUB = '" + cs_cursor.getString(0) + "'", null);
```

Because you have only 1 row in your table, and your are trying to fetch 2nd row using `cs_cursor.getString(1)`

Or try this code,

```
public void getAllEvents() {



    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {




            // Adding contact to list
            MainActivity.Id.add(cursor.getString(0)); //it will store id to my array list "Id"


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


}
```

Comment: what second row?? that cs_cursor is for another table that has valid data(i have confirmed)... and count for after the above query for the second table is 1.... so i find the record... just i am not able to fetch it using subject_cursor.getString(0).